# Coloring particular ggplot ridgeplot in stacked ridgeplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made sets of ridgeplots using ggplot for my data, stratified by week of observation. However, I want to color the ridgeplot so that a particular week is colored differently (e.g., red). I want to draw attention to dynamics that happen following an event at a certain time point, so I figure that will help the audience see the difference better.

Here is an example of my plots:
[image: example plot]

Since my grouping is numerical, I know I have to assign color less intuitively than normal ggplots, per [this example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html).

Here is my code:

```
#ridgeplot
plot_42 = ggplot(sn_sz_week_42, aes(x=L,y=week, group=week))+
  theme_few(base_size = 16)+
  geom_density_ridges()+
  xlab("Shell Length (mm)")+
  ylab("Week")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 30, by = 5))
plot_42
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can add an aes `fill = (week == 10)` to colour week 10 differently from the others, and then play around with `scale_fill_manual` to get the colours you need.

Comment: Ah thanks. Do you have any idea how to remove the legend that this then generates? The usual `theme(legend.title = element_blank())` doesn't get rid of it. Otherwise on the right I get a "week == 10 TRUE FALSE" color legend

Comment: you can try `theme(legend.position="none")`

Comment: In the `scale_fill` statement, add `guide = FALSE`

Comment: Yeah, eventually got it! i actually put `geom_density_ridges(show.legend=FALSE)` and that worked well